# Creating own API using Slim and stucked at one point

Tags: android, api, rest

Can anybody reply to me why the data i am getting are all null. This is what I am getting:

```
{ current_field: null field_count: null lengths: null num_rows: null type: null }
```

I am working on an Android Project in which i am calling an api and showing the response data on the mobile device.

I am stuck on this code below

API Call

```
    $app->get('/sample',function() {
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $res = $db->getAll();

    echoRespnse(200, $res);
});
```

Here I am returning all the records from table to the API and then returning back it to the mobile device from where it was called.

```
        public function getAll($data) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('select * from tab');

        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->get_result();

        $stmt->close();
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Guyies can anybody reply me why the data i am getting all null.This is what I am getting : - {
current_field: null
field_count: null
lengths: null
num_rows: null
type: null
}